How to start jupyter notebook in vscode using jupyter extension with workspace specified
I am currently using the following settings.json file in my .vscode folder
{
    "terminal.integrated.env.windows": {
        "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}"
    }
}

This allows me to run jupyter notebook from the command line. This allows me to have a parent folder for python such that i can run packages in the folder that have not been installed through pip (They are still under development so it does not make sense to pip install them).
How to i update the path on the notebook when i use the jupyter extension to create or open a notebook?
Currently, I am running jupyter notebook and then using the command palette to create a new notebook than I then connect to an existing jupyter server. I can also code os.setwd at the beginning of my code either. I am looking for a simpler workflow than what i am currently doing.

You could try to use python-dotenv .
Using "pip install python-dotenv" to install the package.
To configure the development environment Please add .env file in the root directory of the project:
.
├── . env
└── test. py

Then we can use the following code to load environment:
%load_ext dotenv
%dotenv

